# EF Core | Passing navigation properties in JSON body to API controller as POST request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, json-deserialization

In my project I have a many-to-many relationship between the entity `Course`:

```cs
public class Course : Curriculum
{
    public bool IsPartFunded { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public Course(string id, string name, string description, bool isPartFunded)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.IsPartFunded = isPartFunded;
    }
}
```

and the entity `Subject`:

```cs
public class Subject : Curriculum
{
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public Subject(string id, string name, string description)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
    }
}
```

I have created a POST endpoint in my `CourseController` to create a new `Course` where `_db` is my data context:

```cs
[HttpPost("Course/Create")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Course course)
{
    try
    {
        _db.Course.Add(course);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

How do I now structure the body of my request to not just add a new Course, but also add any associated Subjects to that course?

I have tried the following body JSON in postman (I think this is incorrect):

```json
{
    "Id": "5f4bbbfc-6044-41ed-8cce-a7833717ab61",
    "Name": "Geography",
    "Description": "earth and stuff",
    "IsPartFunded": false,
    "Subjects": [
        {
            "courses": null,
            "name": "rivers",
            "description": "rivers and tings",
            "id": "07c357bf-0015-4f1a-a136-290f5d209eb4"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this did not work and I got the following error back in a 500 response:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
>
> Path:
> $.Entries.Entity.Courses.Subjects.Courses.Subjects.Courses.Subjects.Courses.Subjects.Courses.Subjects.Courses.Subjects.Courses.Subjects.Courses.

I can find a lot of info on how to set up many-to-many relationships in EF Core, however I can find little guidance on how to structure the body of requests sent the the server that runs EF Core.

Comment: Generallly we don't serialize our DB entities so it's not a worry - we decide something else, like how the ViewModel object remembers/transmits the relationship and related entities and then we build the necessary entities on the server, turning the ViewModels into DB Entities. This means it's possible to avoid cycles because the ViewModel graph doesn't contain any, nor does it need to to do its work.. In contrast an object graph of EF entities usually has lots of cycles, because it's possible to infinitely go back and forth between ents using the nav props

Comment: @CaiusJard Interesting, does this mean that the json I tried was infact correct? it was more simply because i am trying to deserialise the JSON directly into DB entities? do you know if there is a way to accomplish this without using the mvc?

Comment: Here's the official docs on avoiding graph cycles in JSON: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution#attaching-a-serialized-graph